# Why do I get error C2228 when compiling my C++ code in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am getting several errors when trying to compile this code:

```
vector<char> vsData(istreambuf_iterator<char>(vsfile), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

renderer.getDevice()-> CreateVertexShader(vsData.data(), vsData.size(), nullptr, &m_vertexShader);
```

The error code is C2228. "left of '.data'/'.size' must have a class type.

Comment: Your first line declares a function named `vsData` taking two parameters and returning `vector<char>`. Google *most vexing parse*.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of code is ambiguous: Obviously, you want to define a `vector` of `char` called `vsData`. However, due to the syntactic ambiguity resolution in C++, called [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (as also mentioned in the comments by @n.m), your first line is interpreted as a function declaration of a function called `vsData` that takes two arguments and returns a `vector` of `char`.

As explained in the article that I linked above, one way to force the compiler to consider your first line as a variable definition is to add an extra pair of parentheses:

```
vector<char> vsData((istreambuf_iterator<char>(vsfile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
                    ^                                 ^
```